# Have Jehovah's Witnesses ever encountered a demon-possessed person in the mission field or in other contexts?

Tags: history, jehovahs-witnesses, missions, demon-possession, testimony

Many Christians of different denominations have reported encounters with demon-possessed individuals. Catholic exorcists are an obvious example. In the mission field, reports of demonic possessions in the [10/40 Window](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82874/how-often-do-missionaries-report-encounters-with-demonic-activity-while-deployed) are not unheard of. An interesting first-hand account by a SDA missionary can be found [here](https://youtu.be/Lh3l9FaRbpM). Even Baptist pastor John Piper has had his [fair share](https://youtu.be/0SK07TY1uh0) of experiences with the exorcism of demon-possessed people.

Have Jehovah's Witnesses ever reported similar encounters with demon-possessed individuals in the mission field or in other contexts?

Comment: Dear down-voter: would you kindly point out the flaws that you see in the question and perhaps suggest some ideas to improve it?

Comment: Not sure why someone thinks this question needs more clarity.  You have provided links to back up claims by other denominations of encountering demon-possessed people.  There are two other related questions still open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jehovah's Witnesses preach in over 240 lands, collectively reporting over 2 billion hours in the ministry annually. I'm sure there are many such encounters with demon-possessed individuals. However, these stories will be quite rare because (1) demon possession is generally rare, and (2) Jehovah's Witnesses don't aim to spread fear of the demons by telling such stories. The ministry is about telling the good news.

I was able to find a couple of experiences published in old Yearbooks and Watchtowers.

- [Watchtower Dec. 1, 1968](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1968886?q=demon%20possessed&p=par#h=11) - brief experience from Corfu island, Greece
- [Watchtower July 15, 1980](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1980526?q=demon%20possessed&p=par#h=35-37) - experience from Godo-olo, Suriname
- [1986 Yearbook of Jehovah's Witnesses](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/301986001?q=demon%20possessed&p=par#h=19) - experience from Chad
- [Watchtower Sept. 1, 1987](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1987642) - detailed experience from Suriname
- [1988 Yearbook of Jehovah's Witnesses](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/301988001?q=demon%20possessed&p=par#h=105) - experience from Malaysia